# For two arrays find items that are present in one array only (symmetric difference)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to compare two arrays and return a new array with any items only found in one of the two given arrays, but not both. In other words, return the symmetric difference of the two arrays.
My algorithm consists of using the map() method on the first array and compare each of element of that array with the elements of the second array using every(). If this method returns true, the element gets returned on the block level of map (which will eventually add it to the returned array) if not it's discarded.
I'm not sure why my code is not working. This is an example of a wrong output using my code:

```
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
    var newArr = arr1
        .map(elem1 => {
            if (arr2.every(elem2 => elem2 != elem1)) {
                return elem1;
            }
        });
    return newArr;
}

console.log(diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

This is the wrong output:
[ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]

The expected output is : [4]

Comment: Diff Two Arrays in Javascript using .map() and .every()***

Comment: `.map()` returns the array of exact same size as `arr1`, but as long as all items of `arr1` are present in `arr2` you don't enter `if(`-body, hence return `undefined` for all of them. You may change `.map()` for `.filter()` to get the desired output.

Comment: Are you looking for a simple algorithm or a fast algorithm? Your algorithm has a complexity of O(n^2). You can solve the problem in O(n log(n))

Comment: do you want a fast method? are the arrays always sorted?

Comment: I'm just hoping to understand why this combination wouldn't work in this specific case. My understanding is that the array constructed from map() is obtained from the returned value of the callback. Hence for example if the 3rd invocation of the callback is false, then the if() statement will not be executed and nothing is returned for that iteration (nothing is pushed to the array obtained eventually from map())

Comment: @YoussefZ : you're supposed to swap places of input arrays, what you do is the opposite - you're basically checking for items of `arr1` not to be present in `arr2`

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov, it makes more sense now. thank you!

Comment: What is the expected result for `[1,2,3]` and `[2,3,4]`? Is it `[1]` or `[4]`depending on what argument goes first, or is it `[1,4]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach iterates the first array and because of using `map` along with the check for the value, you get undefined for every element of `arr1`.

If you take `filter` and the other array as well, you could get the wanted result.

```js
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
    return [
        ...arr1.filter(elem1 => arr2.every(elem2 => elem2 != elem1)),
        ...arr2.filter(elem1 => arr1.every(elem2 => elem2 != elem1))
    ];
}

console.log(diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Another approach takes an array of all values of both arrays and filter by checking if the value is not included in both arrays.

```js
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
    return [...arr1, ...arr2].filter(v => arr1.includes(v) !== arr2.includes(v));
}

console.log(diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Comment: @YoussefZ: as long as neither performance, nor duplicates within input arrays was none of your concerns mentioned in OP, I'll simply leave it as a side note: while above solution may appear neat and easy to grasp, [it is not optimized from performance standpoint](https://jsbench.me/rakge68ow5/1) and returns duplicates if ones are present in source arrays.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov, *"... and returns duplicates if ones are present in source arrays"* where?

Comment: pass `[1,1,2]` and `[2]` and get returned `[1,1]`, whereas `[1]` ***may be*** expected, but wasn't stated explicitly, so I just highlighted that

Comment: yes, this is a real problem with duplicates. thank you for mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Use _.difference(array, [values])

from [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#difference)

or

own solution :

```js
const diffArray = (arrayA, arrayB) => {
    const output = []
    const setA = new Set(arrayA);
    arrayB.forEach((n) =>{
       if(!setA.has(n)){
         output.push(n)
       }
    })
    const setB = new Set(arrayB);
    arrayA.forEach(n =>{
       if(!setB.has(n)){
         output.push(n)
       }
    })
    return output;
}

console.log(diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); //4, 6
```

Comment: The `_.xor()` function is better for this case, since symmetric difference is needed.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm works even when numbers appear multiple times in both arrays.

It uses a Map created from the items of both arrays. The map contains the item as the key, and the value is the amount of times it's found in the 1st array - the number of times it's found it the 2nd array.

After creating the Map, it's converted to an array of [item, count]. The array is then filtered, and all items with a count of `0` are removed (they exist equally in both arrays), and then we map the array to an array of items.

```js
const getCounts = (arr, init = new Map(), inc = 1) =>
  arr.reduce((acc, item) => acc.set(item, (acc.get(item) || 0) + inc), init);

function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  // create a Map that adds 1 for all items in arr1, and substructs 1 for every item in arr2
  const counts = getCounts(arr2, getCounts(arr1), -1);
  
  // convert to an array of pairs [item, count]
  return Array.from(counts)
    .filter(([, v]) => v) // remove all items with count 0
    .map(([k]) => k); // map to the original item
}

console.log(diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(diffArray([1, 2, 3, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(diffArray([5, 1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]));
console.log(diffArray([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns elements of the first array that are not present in the second array.

Its return is explained by the fact that `.map()` returns the array of exact same size as your input (`arr1`), but since all items of `arr1` are present in `arr2` you don't enter `if(`-statement body hence `undefined` is getting returned.

If your intention was to return items that are present in one array only (regardless of the order they're passed in), you may leverage the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object together with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

- combine arrays-arguments into common array of arrays
- loop through those inner arrays with `.reduce()`, building up the `Map`, showing how many times each item is seen within combined array
- for each item of combined array remove duplicates and increment respective counter
- spread resulting `Map` into [`.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) and [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) those to find out uniques

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 5], 
      arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      
      getUniques = (...arrays) => 
        [...arrays
          .reduce((acc, arr) => {
            [...new Set(arr)]
              .forEach(item => 
                acc.set(item, (acc.get(item)||0)+1))
            return acc
          }, new Map)
          .entries()]
          .reduce((acc, [item, repetitions]) => 
            (repetitions == 1 && acc.push(item), acc), [])
            
console.log(getUniques(arr1, arr2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height:100%;}
```

Above approach is of O(n)-time complexity, as opposed to your initial attempt and the answer you have currently accepted (both having O(n²)-time complexity). As a result it may perform ***much*** faster on large arrays (arbitrary number of arrays, as a bonus).